# Changing Javascript variable value with HTML element on click (wavesurfer.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wavesurfer.js

I'm using Wavesurfer.js to visualize waveforms from . Is there a way to use jQuery or Javascript to dynamically change the loaded audio file when I click on an HTML element?

I'm able to visualize a single file, but don't know how to change the loaded file dynamically.

Here's the Wavesurfer.js instance in my footer

```
<script>

var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  backend: 'MediaElement',
    container: '#waveform',
    barWidth: 1,
    barGap: 3,
    cursorColor: '#e15a13',
    cursorWidth: 3,
    mediaControls: true,
    hideScrollbar: true,
    waveColor: "#000000",
    fillParent: true,
    responsive: true,
});

wavesurfer.setHeight(40);
wavesurfer.load('http://dev.chrislamdesign.com/shortwave/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Pharrell-Williams-Happy-Official-Music-Video-1.mp3');

wavesurfer.on('ready', updateTimer)
wavesurfer.on('audioprocess', updateTimer)

// Need to watch for seek in addition to audioprocess as audioprocess doesn't fire
// if the audio is paused.
wavesurfer.on('seek', updateTimer)

function updateTimer() {
  var formattedTime = secondsToTimestamp(wavesurfer.getCurrentTime());
  $('.waveform-time-indicator .time').text(formattedTime);
}

function secondsToTimestamp(seconds) {
  seconds = Math.floor(seconds);
  var h = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
  var m = Math.floor((seconds - (h * 3600)) / 60);
  var s = seconds - (h * 3600) - (m * 60);

  h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
  m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
  s = s < 10 ? '0' + s : s;
  return h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}
</script>
```

I want to replace the loaded file (wavesurfer.load) with an HTML string on click. I'm using Wordpress to loop song results, each have a URL printed in a paragraph tag with the class "move_to_wavesurfer". So, when I click on the song, i want to replace the wavesurfer.load value with the paragraph tag value.

Here's the HTML to inject

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<a class="song-link" data-target="#song-8">
    <img width="606" height="610" src="http://dev.chrislamdesign.com/shortwave/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/cover.png" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://dev.chrislamdesign.com/shortwave/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/cover.png 606w, http://dev.chrislamdesign.com/shortwave/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/cover-150x150.png 150w, http://dev.chrislamdesign.com/shortwave/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/cover-298x300.png 298w" sizes="(max-width: 606px) 100vw, 606px"></a>

<p class="move_to_wavesurfer>http://dev.chrislamdesign.com/shortwave/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/other_song.mp3</p>

</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried executing the script in the Wordpress loop and then replacing the wavesurfer.load value with a PHP value to no avail.  I haven't tried anything with a front end solution. I have no idea how to target a script in jQuery--or even if that's possible.

Comment: Well, - "target a script in jQuery" - isn't a thing... so, I'm just giving you a friendly warning - that if you don't try things... and show your work - then people might downvote this. I'll show you what to do - but you could search the web to learn a little about jQuery. ; )

Comment: I've done a bit of research but haven't found a clean solution to this particular case. I'd love your help @sheriffderek

Comment: Yeah. My point is that 'a little research' isn't enough to post a question.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've done more than a little research. I updated the comment about what I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p>In your PHP loop... maybe you can put the urls in a data attribute</p>

<button rel='song-switch' data-song-url='song-url-a'>
  play
</button>

<button rel='song-switch' data-song-url='other-song-url'>
  play
</button>
```

...

```
console.clear();
// I'd normally write this in plain JavaScript - but since you are using WordPress - it has jQuery already

function switchTrack(url) {
    // your code...
  alert('play the song ' + url);
}

// get references to the HTML(DOM) elements
var $switches = $('[rel="song-switch"]');

// add event listeners to each switch
$switches.each( function() {
  // $(this) refers to each switch
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    var url = $(this).data('song-url'); // get the value of that attr
        //
    switchTrack(url); // pass it into your function - to load a new track
    // and this is where you'd work with the player's api...
    // consider wrapping your current code in a function - or breaking it into some reusable functions
  });
});

// yes... you should use event delegation... but you can look that up in the future.
```

From what I can see of your code - you probably don't have a script file / or aren't using it - so, remember to put this JS in a script tag / or generally - just make sure it's in the right place for you.

Here's where you can learn more about jQuery and all of it's functions: https://jquery.com/

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/teLm7drn

and also... keep in mind that with WordPress... you'll need to wrap your jQuery code with something like this:

```
(function($) {
  // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
  // console.log($);
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Here's a slightly more complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/86fu3vLx/

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I learned a lot just from trying to implement this as well.

Comment: So, for the future - your question wasn't really about wavesurfer at all, right? It was a question about JavaScript event listeners - and how you might get data from the database - into the DOM / and then be able to use it in JavaScript. So - more than one question for sure - and nothing to do with the 3rd party api. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - Glad to help!